# dual boot with windows 7 ubuntu 14 not working

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have 3 hard drives on the PC:

1st drive: 1 TB with windows 7 and 3 partitions.

2nd drive: 500 GB Data.

3rd drive: 40 GB and drive empty where the ubuntu installed itself.

Perfect, now I restart PC only windows boots... 
no ubuntu?

am I missing some kind of boot manager?

Comment: Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

try EasyBCD. it's an aplication for windows to change the bootloader settings.  i've seen some functions of it, but i haven't tested it yet.